# Creating an SQL procedure gives compilation error even though code block runs fine when executed separately

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to run this block of code in a procedure.

```
DECLARE sharedpool FLOAT;
BEGIN
select bytes/1024/1024 into sharedpool from v$sgastat where pool='shared pool' and name like '%free memory';
insert into tempstats1(stat,cdate) values(sharedpool,sysdate);
commit;
END;
```

When run like this it executes successfully and the table is updated.I want to add this block to a procedure and schedule a job to run it periodically.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE temp_insert1 IS
DECLARE sharedpool FLOAT;
BEGIN
select bytes/1024/1024 into sharedpool from v$sgastat where pool='shared pool' and name like '%free memory';
insert into tempstats1(stat,cdate) values(sharedpool,sysdate);
commit;
END;
```

If I run this, it shows a warning that the procedure was created with compilation errors.Why isn't it compiling properly?Can someone please explain where I've gone wrong?

Comment: It just displayed this message: "Warning:Procedure created with compilation errors. "   Is there a way to see the actual error?

Comment: removed my answer because it was valid for mysql.

Comment: Here is the error -  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of
 the following:
 begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>
 <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete
 exists prior external language

Comment: Run `show errors` in order to see the actual compiler error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove `DECLARE` from your stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE temp_insert1
IS
   sharedpool   FLOAT;
BEGIN
   SELECT bytes / 1024 / 1024
     INTO sharedpool
     FROM v$sgastat
    WHERE pool = 'shared pool' AND name LIKE '%free memory';

   INSERT INTO tempstats1 (stat, cdate)
        VALUES (sharedpool, SYSDATE);

   COMMIT;
END;
```

From @DavidAldridge comment:

You can remove your variable declaration like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE temp_insert1
    IS      
    BEGIN

       INSERT INTO tempstats1 (stat, cdate)
       SELECT bytes / 1024 / 1024, SYSDATE
         FROM v$sgastat
        WHERE pool = 'shared pool' AND name LIKE '%free memory';

       COMMIT;
    END;
```

Comment: You don't need to declare that variable at all. Just insert into the table using a select from v$sgastat

Comment: @DavidAldridge: yeah, I agree with you..I just updated my answer. Thanks!